# Error when running django-admin in command line "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asyncio.base_events'"

Tags: python, django, command-line, django-admin

Created the virtual env with pyenv

1. `pyenv init`
2. `pyenv shell 3.9.0`
3. `python -m venv name_of_venv`

Installed Django through pip in a virtual env:
`pip install Django==3.1.7`

Then when I run `django-admin` in cmd line I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/sushensatturu/envs/excel/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/sushensatturu/envs/excel/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
  File "/Users/sushensatturu/envs/excel/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning
  File "/Users/sushensatturu/envs/excel/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/Users/sushensatturu/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to do ... did you create a project before running this command ?.

Comment: I'm trying to run `django-admin startproject` but I can't since there is that error

Comment: so, you tried with `django-admin startproject project_name .` and you got this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed:**

Just had to uninstall and reinstall the python version through pyenv, then create a new virtial environment

Eg.

1. `pyenv uninstall 3.9.0`
2. `pyenv install 3.9.0`